# Batch Files - If output <=2 do this, if output >2 do that (Perform action dependent on output)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to perform an action depending on this statements output:

```
wmic process where name="test.exe" | find "test.exe" /c

if the output is <=2 do echo two or less

if the output is >2 do echo more than two
```

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

set them to variables then compare also you want switches before the search string =D

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 USEBACKQ delims=:" %%F IN (`command ^| find /C "test.exe"`) DO (
  SET var=%%F
)

IF %var% LEQ 2 ECHO Two or Less
IF %var% GTR 2 ECHO More than Two
```

EDIT: (for Jeb <3)

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 USEBACKQ delims=:" %%F IN (`command ^| find /C "test.exe"`) DO (
  SET var=%%F
)

IF %var% LEQ 2 (
 ECHO Two or Less
) ELSE ( 
 ECHO More than Two
)
```

Comment: You could also use ELSE, `if %var% LEQ 2 (echo Two or less) ELSE (echo more than two)`

Comment: If they're longer commands I use ELSE, but for the sake of keeping it looking clean I just do the other IF =D